# Convert elements in a numpy array to string

Tags: arrays, string, numpy

I wrote the following script to load data from CSV file in numpy array form:

```
import numpy

sample = numpy.genfromtxt('sample_cor.csv', delimiter = ',')
print sample
```

and this **sample** looked like:

```
[[  259463.392   2737830.062 ]
 [  255791.4823  2742050.772 ]
 [  249552.4949  2746152.328 ]
 [  247925.1228  2746422.143 ]
 [  262030.4697  2728966.229 ]
 [  260462.1936  2731412.856 ]
 [  260644.0281  2735003.027 ]
 [  268588.7974  2732835.097 ]]
```

now I want to extract every row in this array to string with a comma, for example, I expected row 1 to be converted to `259463.392,2737830.062`, row 2 to be `255791.4823,2742050.772`, and so on.

I tried the code below:

```
ss = numpy.array_str(sample[0])
print ss
print type(ss)
```

and got the result maybe not what I want,

```
[  259463.392  2737830.062]
<type 'str'>
```

(I used `coords = '259467.2,2737833.87'` and got the string form which was what I want:
`259467.2,2737833.87`)

How to convert elements in a numpy array to string with a comma?

Comment: The form without the `,` is just the normal way that `numpy` arrays are displayed.  It helps distinguish them from Python lists.  The `,` is not an integral part of either a list or an array.  It's just a display feature.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`join method`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) -

```
[",".join(item) for item in a.astype(str)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [141]: a
Out[141]: 
array([[  259463.392 ,  2737830.062 ],
       [  255791.4823,  2742050.772 ],
       [  249552.4949,  2746152.328 ],
       [  247925.1228,  2746422.143 ],
       [  262030.4697,  2728966.229 ],
       [  260462.1936,  2731412.856 ],
       [  260644.0281,  2735003.027 ],
       [  268588.7974,  2732835.097 ]])

In [142]: [",".join(item) for item in a.astype(str)]
Out[142]: 
['259463.392,2737830.062',
 '255791.4823,2742050.772',
 '249552.4949,2746152.328',
 '247925.1228,2746422.143',
 '262030.4697,2728966.229',
 '260462.1936,2731412.856',
 '260644.0281,2735003.027',
 '268588.7974,2732835.097']
```

Comment: thank you for the advice, but I have a little question that why the showing of mine of numpy array in the post lack comma?

Comment: @Heinz Hmm if the input is a NumPy array, it should. Or else, you could try `print(repr(a))`.

Comment: Thank you, repr() returns the having-comma array.

Comment: @Divakar is there a "pure" numpy solution to this and would that make it faster for large datasets? Thank you

Comment: I am very late to the party, though!
hey @Heinz, since you're printing that Numpy array via `print()`, it doesn't display the commas. Try simply running the variable in a single Jupyter cell - then, elements display with commas.